# Cocoa pods gives ruby permission denied error after I updated it on osx mavericks

Tags: macos, cocoa, rubygems, cocoapods

I have searched everywhere, the problem seems similar, but it is not. I was working using pod and needed to update it. Once I issued 
`sudo gem update`
there were so many errors, but cocoa pod got update to the latest. Now where I run pod with any option I get the following errors:

```
Last login: Mon Apr 21 03:48:44 on ttys000
mdhossain@Mds-MacBook-Pro ~ $ pod --version
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:212:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.16.1/lib/xcodeproj.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
mdhossain@Mds-MacBook-Pro ~ $
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I have reinstalled cocoapod and yet this did not solve the problem. Help you be much appreciated.

Comment: I am also getting the same error! Are you using OSX Yosemite? That's what I am using and I have the same error

Comment: No. I am using Mavericks. I solved this problem by installing a local version of ruby. I don't quite remember what it was.

Comment: I am using Yosemite and have a similar problem.

Comment: Try installing rake https://rubygems.org/gems/rake. I think that's how I solved my issue...

Comment: Now, this was an issue when I had mavericks, but I got similar issue when I install yosemite. I actually solved it from the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite

Answer (score 2):

I has the same issue when I updated to Yosemite. 
I sort out by updating gem packages, using...

```
$ sudo gem update
```

After updating `$pod update` or `$pod install` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I update to Yosemite Beta 2.

I solved my problem by running **xcode-select --install** in my terminal.
That will install/update rubygems.

Once the update is done, I had to launch pod update twice to see the result.
But that's works for me.

Comment: This did not work for me. I used a lot from this following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite